# jQuery generate password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Now I'm using:

```
$generate = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8);
```

and

```
$('#generateNew').on('click', function () {
    var generated = "<?=$generate;?>";
    $.post('', function( data ) {
        //...on success alert(generated);
```

But I want to move this javascript to .js file, not on the same page as php `$generate`, then my question will be. How can I generate same password as in `$generate`but only in js? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why on the world do you need to use md5 when PHP has password_hash ? You can store $generate in db or in a file and do a simple ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem you want to encrypt a random number in hash format so you can use `Math.random()` function to generate a random number and to encrypt to MD5 hash by using

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script>                                                                      
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(Math.random());    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript library for that.
as example

```
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5
```

Or you can keep your md5 string in hidden input in html and access it via javascript if its only problem to keep javascript separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign this passoword to any other parameter in the same php/jsp file as below inside script tag.

```
var globalTempPass = "<?=$generate;?>";
```

And then you can use this in another js file (say temp.js) where you have written your code.

```
$('#generateNew').on('click', function () {
    var generated = globalTempPass; //change
    $.post('', function( data ) {
        //...on success alert(generated);
```

Make sure you include this new js in the HTML/JSP/PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/tq6xwea2/

`CreateRandomPassword(Length, isUpperAlpha, isLowerAlpha, isNumaric ,SpecialChars)`

I have developed easy function to generate password